# How to restrict user defined variable value to specific thread group in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

In my jmeter script, i have 2 thread group and User Defined Variables respectively. In user defined variables i'm using the name but with different values in each thread group. When i run the jmx file, i see the value of 2nd thread group had override the 1st thread group. I need to run the thread group with different values for same user defined variable name. Requesting to help me in resolving this issue. Below is the sample screenshot how the jmx file designed.
[image: Screenshot of 1st thread group with user defined variable]

[image: Screenshot of 2nd thread group with user defined variable]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [User Defined Variarbles documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables)

> For defining variables during a test run, see User Parameters. UDVs are processed in the order they appear in the Plan, from top to bottom.
>
> For simplicity, it is suggested that UDVs are placed only at the start of a Thread Group (or perhaps under the Test Plan itself).

So I believe you should consider migrating to [User Parameters](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters) instead.

Check out [A Quick Guide to JMeter PreProcessors](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/quick-guide-jmeter-preprocessors) for comprehensive information on `User Parameters` and other [Pre-Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors) with detailed explanation, examples, etc.

Comment: This looks like a best option to use User Parameters for the new design. Jmx file which i'm running is merged using 100 different jmx files. Any workaround solution to work with make use of user defined variables itself